# How to remove "Desktop" option from Alt-Tab menu?

Tags: unity, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing “Show Desktop” from application switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167263/removing-show-desktop-from-application-switcher)

When I press Alt-Tab it display all opened programs and desktop icon. I never use this desktop option and it is very annoying when you switch between other. I am a developer and use Alt-Tab very often. Is it possible to disable the desktop option?