# How can I remove "Show Desktop" icon from alt-tab?

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove “Desktop” option from Alt-Tab menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72687/how-to-remove-desktop-option-from-alt-tab-menu)

Is it possible to remove "Show Desktop" icon when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> applications?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoD7Z.png]

Thanks !