# How can I remove "Show Desktop" from the Alt-Tab (application) switcher?

Tags: unity, application-switcher

Is it possible to remove "Show Desktop" from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> application switcher?

Comment: You are using Unity, correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have specified. I went to the Unity settings in CompizConfig but didn't find any visible option for that. Just wondering if there is a hidden option or if it's just simply somewhere else.

Comment: You are correct; I couldn't find it there, either. I'm not sure if there might be another way to go about it, however.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### It can be done!

I've uploaded a Unity build *for 12.04* that fixes this (no Show Desktop in the Alt-Tab switcher).

- **To install**, open a terminal and:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:izx/askubuntu -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

- You can enable the "Show Desktop Icon" setting in the Unity Plugin in Compiz (using `ccsm`) to get the icon on the Launcher on the left:

  [image]
- If/when a new Unity update is released, Update Manager will download it automatically. I will try to "fix" the update and put it in the PPA as soon as possible; please add a comment to this answer to alert me if you upgrade and "Show Desktop" re-appears in the Switcher!

#### How did you do it?

I modified the Unity Source. It consists of two steps:

1. Comment out line 900 in [`plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1124369/), which by default adds the "Show Desktop" icon to the switcher:

```
// results.push_back(pimpl->desktop_icon_);
```

2. Change line 1638 in `plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp` from:

   ```
     if (!(results.size() == 1 && results[0]->GetIconType() == AbstractLauncherIcon::IconType::TYPE_DESKTOP))
   ```

   to

   ```
     if (!results.size() == 0))
   ```

   - While the list of Alt-Tab switcher icons was at least 1 before (the show-desktop icon), now it is 0 and we need to modify this to show the switcher only when there is at least one item in the list (i.e. at least one app running).

Comment: It looks like the current version of unity is 5.20, and your version is 5.14. I'm using 12.04, so a custom build seems to be my only option.
Thanks for outlining this. If you don't have time to do the build, maybe I'll try it.

Comment: I spent some time and recompiled it myself for 5.20. I've posted my answer below, since it wasn't quite as straight forward as I imagined: http://askubuntu.com/a/395031/17065

Comment: does not work for 12.04

Comment: for 12.04 and up look the next answer

Answer (score 105):

### 13.04 and newer

For 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04, to enable or disable the "Show desktop" option in application switcher you can use [unity-tweak-tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool)

[image: Install unity-tweak-tool]

[image: pic]

### 12.10

For 12.10, a new [setting has been added](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1014346) to CCSM to enable or disable the "Show desktop" option in application switcher.

Run this command in a terminal to install CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now open CCSM and go to Ubuntu Unity plugin.

[image: Ubuntu Unity plugin]

Switch to *Switcher* tab. Then tick the check box next to *Disable Show Desktop in the switcher* option.

[image: Disable the show desktop]

[image: Tada! No more "Show desktop" in application switcher!.]

Comment: Thank you. I've disabled it using Unity Tweak Tool but your response sent me there. Ubunt 13.10.(Disabled it because sometimes it switches to Desktop)

Comment: unity-tweak-tool works in 13.10, too.

Comment: Wonderful, works in 14.04, thank you!

Comment: works in 14.10 too. I think this should be the correct answer.

Comment: `unity-tweak-tool` works in 15.04 ..

Comment: `unity-tweak-tool` works in 15.10

Comment: `unity-tweak-tool` works in 16.04 as well

Comment: `unity-tweak-tool` works in 17.04

Answer (score 8):

In 14.04, I was able to accomplish this in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

By visiting:

- "Desktop" section of the listing in the wide, white, right area →
- "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" item →
- "Switcher" tab →
- "Disable Show Desktop in the Switcher" item.

This was a default, uncustomized C.C.S.M. straight from the repos.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to [revert back to the behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> prior to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68151/revert-alt-tab-behavior-changed-in-11-10).

I realize that this is a bit drastic, but it might be better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm not sure if this is of any help to you, however while using Unity 2D, sick of not having graphics drivers I dived into gnome fall-back. Then unsatisfied, I left back to the Unity interface. I no longer have the displayed "Show Desktop" in the ALT+TAB application switcher. I believe this to be a side effect of the Gnome interface having it set in the lower left hand corner, and when I switched back, I no longer had it. Seemed to work for me... worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. How risky is this approach? I can't afford putting the stability of my work environment in jeopardy.

Comment: For me, I had no issues with this otherwise, however I'm also not 100% sure that was it. If you have VM it might be nice to test this theory, I also edited the panels a lot, removing and adding items such as workspace switchers and the trash icon to replace the real feel of gnome that 10.10 had. I wouldn't think too risky, but worth a try. If you're really that worried you could back up everything, but it shouldn't do anything out of the ordinary. I also might have just gotten a lucky bug. I don't know, I'll test this myself as well. See what I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I got this to work exactly once. When I restarted, I had two instances of unity running, and couldn't figure out why or how. killing them didn't work, and uninstalling reinstalling didn't help.

I resolved it by installing 13.10. I'll use the other fixes listed here.

I couldn't get this to work in 12.04, [the package](https://launchpad.net/~izx/+archive/askubuntu) provided [in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170982/17065) wasn't new enough (version 5.14), and the guide wasn't quite flawless. (though it was very helpful)
Here's how I managed to apply the fix for unity 5.20

1) Download the source:

```
sudo apt-get source unity
```

2) Change the source:

```
diff -ru org/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp patch/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp
--- unity-5.20.0/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp  2013-04-12 04:24:42.000000000 -0400
+++ unity-diff/plugins/unityshell/src/LauncherController.cpp    2013-12-23 12:22:50.154961579 -0500
@@ -761,7 +761,7 @@
 {
   std::vector<AbstractLauncherIcon::Ptr> results;

-  results.push_back(pimpl->desktop_icon_);
+  //results.push_back(pimpl->desktop_icon_);

   for (auto icon : *(pimpl->model_))
   {
diff -ru org/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp patch/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp
--- unity-5.20.0/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp  2013-04-12 04:24:42.000000000 -0400
+++ unity-diff/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp    2013-12-23 12:24:36.718966737 -0500
@@ -1909,7 +1909,8 @@

   auto results = launcher_controller_->GetAltTabIcons(show_mode == switcher::ShowMode::CURRENT_VIEWPORT);

-  if (!(results.size() == 1 && results[0]->GetIconType() == AbstractLauncherIcon::IconType::TYPE_DESKTOP))
+//  if (!(results.size() == 1 && results[0]->GetIconType() == AbstractLauncherIcon::IconType::TYPE_DESKTOP))
+  if (!(results.size() == 0))
     switcher_controller_->Show(show_mode, switcher::SortMode::FOCUS_ORDER, false, results);

   return true;
```

3) Install other packages:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep unity
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

5) Run cmake.

```
cd <source folder>
# from the INSTALL file
mkdir build; cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCOMPIZ_PLUGIN_INSTALL_TYPE=package -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/unity
make
sudo make install
```

Note: if you set your DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX folder to `/usr` instead of `/opt/unity`, you won't have to rsync later, but I wanted to try linking the file first. I gave up.

I suppose to undo the best option is to reinstall unity, which would put the standard files overtop.

6) Replace the files:

```
sudo rsync -av /opt/unity/ /usr/
```

7) Reinstall unity-greeter. Apparently the files rsynced break unity-greeter. Which is apparently needed to get unity running.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `dconf` to [manage your Unity settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589974/how-can-i-transfer-my-unity-settings-from-one-machine-to-another), then the path to this setting (by inspection with `dconf watch /`) is:

```
/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/disable-show-desktop
```

Set this to `true` and the desktop will be removed as an `alt-tab` option.