# Is it possible to hide the "Show Desktop" icon in application switcher?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to hide the "Show Desktop" icon in the application switcher (when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)?

It's very annoying when you have a workflow, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> one time too much and every window is minimised.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: [How can I remove “Show Desktop” from the Alt-Tab (application) switcher?](http://askubuntu.com/q/167263/52726)

Comment: [Question all ready answered here, its for 12.04  ][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/167263/how-can-i-remove-show-desktop-from-the-alt-tab-application-switcher

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry for the duplicate, couldn't find the other questions.