# Super+D key shortcut does not show desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys

I recently installed Saucy Salamander on my computer. Previously in Ringtail, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> used to show the desktop. However for this release, the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does not seem to work properly... Is it a bug?

Comment: The shortcut is Ctrl + Super + D.

Answer (score 100):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't work starting with Ubuntu 13.10. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> instead, I tested it and it works.

How to change the keys:

Open the Dash and type `keyboard`. There should be an app called *Keyboard*. Click on it and then go to the *Shortcuts* tab. Click on the *Navigation* list entry and scroll down until you see **Hide all normal windows**, click on it and create a new shortcut, for example:

> <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

And that's it, you're done.

Comment: I did that and super + D doesn't work more than once.
Ctrl + Super + D works as expected, and it's interesting, once I'm in the desktop after I pressed Ctrl + Super + D, Super + D works.
I am on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Fixed!! It has to be changed in the compiz settings into the unity plugin. These are the steps: install compizconfig-settings-manager, go to ubuntu unity plugin, and change the entry of "Show desktop" for what you want. It asked me that super + D was already taken for other shortcut (which did also show desktop), so I chose to proceed anyway.

Comment: Start with 13.10? Well I'm on 12.04 LTS and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Akronix Your tip is helping me for the last 2 years now. Still timely on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 41):

It is not a bug. In order to make <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to work you must to go to **System Settings** → **Appearance**, select **Behavior** tab and tick **And show desktop icon to the launcher**:

[image: Appearance - Behavior]

If you don't like to have the desktop icon on your launcher, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut.

Or you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to desktop:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you saved me! Who on earth has implemented it in this strange way!?

Answer (score 10):

With the CompizConfig Settings Manager, you can enable the <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shortcut to show desktop without having that annoying icon in the launcher.

Just open CompizConfig and go to Desktop >> Ubuntu Unity Plugin >> General and change the show desktop shortcut. [image: Show Desktop shortcut config] In the Switcher tab there, you can also disable having the Desktop icon in the Alt-Tab menu.

Comment: Re disabling Show-Desktop from Alt-Tab, see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/167263/how-can-i-remove-show-desktop-from-the-alt-tab-application-switcher#506655

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same issue with Ubuntu 17.04, but managed to fix it by following the instructions [suggested by Akronix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364424/superd-key-shortcut-does-not-show-desktop/924385#comment616818_364430).

The steps are as follows:

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager by typing

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run the manager, type "unity" in the Filter text field and select **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**
3. Find **Show Desktop** in the list and update it with the desired combination

Thanks to Akronix for finding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**For 11.10 and 12.10**

`Control`-`Alt`-`D` shows the desktop for me

**For 12.04 ,13.04 and 14.04**

`Control`-`Super`-`D` works for me

Comment: Also works in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

The official hotkey to show desktop in Ubuntu is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
But if you want to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you can try my steps:
1. Open **dconf Editor**
2. Go to com => canonical => unity => launcher.
3. Click on favorites's value column and go to eol
4. Add `, 'unity://desktop-icon'` before `]`.
Now you see Show Desktop shortcut on Unity Launcher. In the future, you can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show desktop.

Comment: This has already been answered before in a much easier method by Radu Rădeanu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 L.T.S.

Go to *Settings* → *Devices* → *Keyboard* → *Navigation* section.

Click "Hide all normal windows" which is probably set to "disabled". Enter your new keyboard shortcut, which I set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Voila! Instant desktop!

Answer (score 0):

1 - System Settings → Appearance

2 - [image]

3 - run on command: gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites

4 - copy the given list and delete 'unity://desktop-icon'

5 - run on command: gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites [GIVEN LIST WITHOUT 'unity://desktop-icon']

6 - CompizConfig → General Options → Key Bindings

7 - Set "Show desktop" shortcut

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing @Radu Rădeanu's answer,

Step 1: 
Change the shortcut to   Super + D  in  settings->keyboard->shortcuts->Navigation->"Hide all normal windows.

Step 2:
Go to Settings->Appearance->Behavior, tick Add show desktop icon to launcher.

Now it defenitly works