# Hide all normal windows shortcut is not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 13.10, minimize, navigation

Hide all normal windows shortcut is not working. It is currently set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. And changing the shortcut doesn't help (tried <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>). However other shortcuts work fine (even from the same Navigation tab).

I guess the question is a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361676/how-to-have-a-functioning-minimize-all-windows-shortcut-on-saucy) which is unanswered.

Update: It works exactly one time after reboot. I can minimize windows and even bring them back using the combination but only once. 
Also switching keyboard layout shortcut stopped working, but as I can see it's a [known bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356357/how-to-use-altshift-combo-to-switch-keyboard-layout-in-13-10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there's a good post on how to make it work again, fairly simply too:
[Super+D key shortcut does not show desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364424/superd-key-shortcut-does-not-show-desktop-in-ubuntu-13-10)

The trick is to tick the "Add Show Desktop Icon to the Launcher" in the Appearance settings. Once you have it there then you can define your shortcut for the Show Desktop and it should work (at least it worked for me).

Have fun...

Comment: Thank you for the link. Seems like the right solution to me so I mark it accepted. (Can't really check it though, because already installed xfce)

Comment: Wow, yet more useful functionality that is hidden for no decent reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about this bug: [Bug #1217196: Keyboard shortcuts not working with GNOME 3.9.90](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1217196).

Anyway, you don't need to reboot your system. After you add a new or edit an existing shortcut, if this doesn't work, the only thing that you have to do is to log out and log back in and your new shortcut "should" work after this.

Comment: Sorry. Unity tag accidentally got erased. So this gnome bug has nothing to do with it, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the initial question. Resetting the shortcut doesn't help. You can only use the shortcut once before it breaks. I have to logout/login to make it wotk again. And then, too, it only works once.