# How to change "Hide all normal windows" shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Now I can use Super+D to hide all windows. I want to change it to Ctrl+D or something like this. I go to settings and set it:

[image: keyboard settings screenshot]

but nothing changes. When I open all shortcuts pressing Super I see that it now shows Ctrl+D but I can hide windows only using the old Super+D. I added "show desktop" button and I tried to reload the computer, but nothing changes.

**Edit:**

**Strange thing:** after restarting or logging out ctrl+d shortcut works exactly 1 time. It hides windows, then shows windows, then stops working

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I`m using 16.04

Comment: Your edit saved my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Settings (`unity-control-center`) can't be used to change this shortcut. You have to use CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM).

1. Install CCSM. Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open CCSM
3. Go to **Desktop** section → **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** → **General** tab
4. Change the **Show Desktop** shortcut

   [image: CCSM screenshot]

This is based on [Prime624's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/557768/301745) on a related question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to log out and back in, or restart the computer.

I've experienced the same thing when changing Super shortcuts. I don't know why exactly it happens, but it seems like changes only take effect when you start a new X session (by logging out and back in).

Comment: Whoops, I may have missed the last sentence in the question. I assume "reload" means "restart", but let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Strange thing: after restarting or logging out ctrl+d shortcut works exactly 1 time. It hides windows, then shows windows, then stops working