# How can I transfer my Unity settings from one machine to another?

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

I have  customized Unity in Ubuntu 14.04 quite heavily on my laptop. Now I have also installed Ubuntu on my desktop machine and I want to reuse the config file.

I have customized it with unity-teak-tool and ccsm. ccsm has the option to export a config file but this crashed Ubuntu on my desktop machine.

How can I transfer my Unity settings from my laptop to my desktop machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line you can use

```
dconf dump /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ > ccsm.cfg
```

to save the settings from CCSM into `ccsm.cfg` and restore them using

```
dconf load /org/compiz/profiles/unity/ < ccsm.cfg
```

For the setting from unity-teak-tool it depends on what you changed there as different settings are stored on different places.

[Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/) is another configuration tool for Unity (written by me) that lets you save your settings into and load from a file. It doesn't support all the options that unity-tweak-tools has, but maybe it has the ones you need.