# How can I have a "show desktop" icon when scrolling through opened applications using Alt+Tab in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, application-switcher

I want to see a "show desktop" icon when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (i.e. in the Application-switcher).

My question is the opposite of [How can I remove "Show Desktop" from the Alt-Tab (application) switcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/167263/487981)

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

I have installed GNOME Tweak Tool which I think may help, but I don't know how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3):

This is not implemented in Gnome Shell, the desktop used by Ubuntu 18.04. In many cases, gnome extensions can implement desired features, but I do not know of an extension that specifically meets your desire to have a "Show Desktop" icon in the application switcher.

To quickly show the desktop, you can set up a hotkey to hide all windows at once (i.e., show desktop). In Settings - Keyboard, find "Hide all normal windows" under "Navigation" and assign it a shortcut, for example Super+d.

A hack you might try, if you think it is worth it, is to create a "Show desktop" launcher as outlined in [this Askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903532/can-i-add-show-desktop-to-the-gnome-dash). Pin it as a favorite to your Dock (or Dash if using pure Gnome). Then install the extension [Super+Tab launcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1133/supertab-launcher/), which is well maintained at the time of writing. This extension includes your not running favorites in the Alt+Tab switcher. It thus will also contain your launcher to minimize all windows. The catch however is that all favorites will now be in the launcher, unless you remove the other favorites from the dock/dash.